# How to get a dictionary and all its elements by key?

Tags: python, search, dictionary

I have a structure like this:

```
{
    "content": "Name 1", 
    "name": "directory", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": "Name 2", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }, 
        {
            "content": "Name 3", 
            "name": "subdirectory_two", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "subsubdirectory", 
                    "decendent": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to look for the name (name is a string and unique), and if I found it - save the whole dictionary in other variable. E.g.:

I'm looking for "subdirectory", i should get:

```
       {
            "content": "Name 2", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }
```

and save it in the variable.

How to perform this search in Python?

Comment: Recursion is your friend.

Comment: You cannot get `null` as it is not a valid literal in Python. Did you mean `None`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: yes, its None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive function checking the name of the current dictionary, and if that name matches return the dictionary, and otherwise try the "descendants", if any, and return if those have a match.

```
def find_name(d, name):
    if d["name"] == name:
        return d
    for d2 in d["decendent"] or []:
        res = find_name(d2, name)
        if res:
            return res
```

Example:

```
>>> dictionary = { your dictionary }
>>> print find_name(dictionary, "subdirectory")
{'content': 'Name 2', 'name': 'subdirectory', 'decendent': None}
```

Comment: If I were the OP I would make a directory with no descendants hold an empty list instead of `None`.  It would make the API more consistent.  And it would allow you to get rid of the `or []`.